# Could you please help me locate this hymn?

Tags: hymns, reference-request

I heard a sermon that was recorded in the 1980s.  The speaker was [Dr. Paul E. Toms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_E._Toms), who at the time was senior pastor at [Park Street Church in Boston, Massachusetts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Street_Church).  In his sermon, Dr. Toms referenced a hymn, but he didn't mention the title.  My mother and I would really like to find this hymn.  We would be very grateful for any clues or ideas that you might have!  Here is what I know:

The hymn is about a man who lived and died.  At the gates of Heaven, the gatekeeper said, "On whose authority should I let you in?  The man replied:

> "I come in the name of Jesus.
>   For me He bled and died."
>   And the pearly gates swung open
>   and welcomed him inside.

This was all that Dr. Toms mentioned about the hymn itself; unfortunately, he did not mention the title.  Dr. Toms did mention that a certain visitor to Park Street Church, "Bill Hoyt" (or possibly "Hoight" or similar; since I only have the sermon on audio, I don't know the spelling) sang this hymn at the church.  (But since I'm not sure if "Bill Hoyt" is a famous person or not, I'm not sure if this is a helpful bit of information.)

Unfortunately, this is all that I know.  We will be really grateful for any clues that you might have!  Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a google search.


Comment: @Narnian Hi and thank you!  Yeah, this is basically a search question, but so far I haven't been able to find the hymn on Google.

Comment: Ah, but a simple google search does not reveal the answer

Comment: I suggest you send an email to this person who knew Toms and pose the question: http://www.gordonconwell.edu/academics/view-faculty-member.cfm?faculty_id=15902&grp_id=8947 They were both faculty at Gordon-Conwell Theological Seminary. Perhaps this person heard the sermon.

Comment: The refrain for ["He the Pearly Gates Will Open"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RK_5efVHxs) is close to your quoted part. Probably not what you are looking for, though. "He the pearly gates will open,
So that I may enter in;
For He purchased my redemption
And forgave me all my sin."

Comment: This wouldn't be the first time that a preacher says some rhyme, but calls it a hymn. Can you link to the sermon or give us the exact date and location to look it up?

Comment: I have sometimes found hymns at this site, by searching with the melody:  [himnary.org](http://www.hymnary.org/melody/search)

Comment: @Andrew Are you sure this is a hymn, or is it just a song or poem? That might help in locating it

Answer (score 2):

I think your song might be [This One's With Me](http://www.lyrics.net/lyric/2585494) by NewSong.  I stumbled across the service's [lyrics](http://www.lyrics.net/lyrics) while searching for another set of lyrics and found a combination of terms from your quote that located **This One's With Me**.

> I was dreaming about Heaven
>   Dreamed I was standing at the Pearly Gates
>   We're all there and I was so scared
>   In the presence of One so great
>
> I felt so worried and worthy 
> I felt like running away 
> I bowed my head
>   and I turn to go 
> When I heard someone say
>
> "Father, this one's with me 
> Part of the family 
> One of the reasons I
>   died on Calvary 
> Father, welcome him in 
> I paid the price for him
>   
> Father, oh Father, this one's with me"
>
> I was dreaming about Heaven 
> When I looked up the gates were opened
>   wide 
> And in the distance, I saw Jesus 
> Our eyes met and I began to cry
>
> Angels robed in their beauty 
> Were there to show me the way 
> And all of
>   Heaven singing 
> When I heard His voice say
>
> "Father, this one's with me 
> Part of the family 
> One of the reasons I
>   died on Calvary 
> Father, welcome him in 
> I paid the price for him
>   
> Father, oh Father"
>
> Finally, we were there face to face 
> And He placed on me Heaven's crown
>   
> I fell down on my knees, laid my crown at His feet 
> Then He said to me
>
> "Father, this one's with me 
> Part of the family 
> One of the reasons I
>   died on Calvary 
> Father, welcome him in 
> I paid the price for him
>   
> Father, oh Father, this one's with me"

Answer (score 2):

Some would argue that a text about a man who lived and died is a "spiritual song", and not a hymn, as one commonly accepted definition of a hymn is "A song in Praise of God". Having written that, I would not be at all surprised to find that the stanza did, in fact come from a text included in a hymnal. The problem is, many hymnals index the texts they include by the first line, and some omit the title altogether, even if the original poet included one. And to make the task even more difficult, nearly every hymnal and spiritual song book I know of indexes the first line of only the first stanza, so knowing the first line of the refrain or of stanza other than the first is usually not much help. Further, there have been many hymnals, and collections of books of spiritual songs which have not yet been catalogued.

First, I suggest you contact the church music department of [Park Street Church](http://www.parkstreet.org/ministries/music), and see if the music director recognizes the bit you quote. It may be included in a hymnal used by the church with which he is familiar.

If that doesn't help, I suggest you contact [The Hymn Society](http://www.thehymnsociety.org/) of the US and Canada and see if they can refer you to someone who might be able to better help you.

I would also contact the music departments at the [Moody Bible Institute](https://www.moody.edu/) in Chicago, and [Southwestern Baptist Theological Seminary](https://swbts.edu/) in Fort Worth, TX, and see if someone there, or in the respective libraries of those institutions might know of the text, or be able to refer you to someone who might.

You might also contact the [Billy Graham Evangelistic Organization](https://billygraham.org/) and see if there is someone there who might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this hymn was sung by Bill Hoyt. I had the old LP. I recorded the alblum on C.D. and have this hymn.

Comment: Hi jerry. Thanks for contributing. But this answer doesn't help us if you don't give the name of the hymn.

Comment: Thanks for your input. If you know the name of the album, or the name of some of the songs on it, it might be possible to search for full album details. I couldn't identify a Christian singer named Bill Hoyt, either. If you know more about him that might also help.

Answer (score -4):

I believe you are referencing the lyrics for "Jesus loves me" by William Batchelder Bradbury (1816–1868)

> Jesus loves me! This I know,
>   For the Bible tells me so.
>   Little ones to Him belong;
>   They are weak, but He is strong.
>
> *Yes, Jesus loves me!
>
>   Yes, Jesus loves me!
>
>   Yes, Jesus loves me!
>
>   The Bible tells me so.*
>
> Jesus loves me! This I know,
>   As He loved so long ago,
>   Taking children on His knee,
>   Saying, “Let them come to Me.”
>
> *Yes, Jesus loves me!...*
>
> Jesus loves me still today,
>   Walking with me on my way,
>   Wanting as a friend to give
>   Light and love to all who live.
>
> *Yes, Jesus loves me!...*
>
> Jesus loves me! He who died
>   Heaven’s gate to open wide;
>   He will wash away my sin,
>   Let His little child come in.
>
> *Yes, Jesus loves me!...*
>
> Jesus loves me! He will stay
>   Close beside me all the way;
>   Thou hast bled and died for me,
>   I will henceforth live for Thee.
>
> *Yes, Jesus loves me!...*

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. Although I've edited this, I don't believe it's the right answer. There is no mention of "pearly gates" and it's in the wrong meter.